# Unity3d apk fail

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, apk

Right after I open my apk it instantly crashes and I'm pretty sure that it works as an exe file or in unity player. It even works on my device with Unity Remote.

Here is my logcat related errors: ( The process name is com.Vali.Atomic )

```
I/ActivityManager(  515): Displayed com.Vali.Atomic/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerNativeActivity: +1s90ms
D/Unity   ( 4500): GL_OES_rgb8_rgba8 GL_OES_EGL_sync GL_OES_surfaceless_context GL_OES_fbo_render_mipmap GL_NV_depth_nonlinear GL_NV_draw_path GL_NV_d
raw_texture GL_NV_texture_npot_2D_mipmap GL_OES_EGL_image GL_OES_EGL_image_external GL_OES_vertex_half_float GL_OES_mapbuffer GL_NV_draw_buffers GL_NV
_multiview_draw_buffers GL_EXT_Cg_shader GL_EXT_packed_float GL_OES_texture_half_float GL_EXT_texture_array GL_OES_compressed_ETC1_RGB8_texture GL_EXT
_texture_compression_latc GL_NV_texture_compression_latc GL_EXT_texture_compression_dxt1 GL_EXT_texture_compression_s3tc GL_NV_texture_compression_s3t
c GL_EXT_texture_filter_anisotropic GL_NV_get_tex_image GL_NV_read_buffer GL_NV_shader_framebuffer_fetch GL_NV_copy_image GL_NV_fbo_color_attachments
GL_EXT_bgra GL_EXT_texture_format_BGRA8888 GL_EXT_read_format_bgra GL_EXT_unpack_subimage GL_NV_pack_subimage GL_NV_texture_compression_s3tc_update GL
_NV_read_depth GL_NV_read_stencil GL_NV_uniform_buffer_object GL_NV_map_buffer_range GL_EXT_robustness GL_OES_standard_derivatives GL_NV_EGL_s
D/Unity   ( 4500): tream_consumer_external GL_EXT_separate_shader_objects GL_NV_copy_buffer GL_NV_3dvision_settings GL_EXT_debug_marker GL_EXT_debug_l
abel GL_KHR_debug GL_EXT_texture_storage GL_NV_pixel_buffer_object GL_NV_framebuffer_blit GL_NV_non_square_matrices GL_NV_explicit_attrib_location GL_
OES_vertex_array_object GL_NV_smooth_points_lines GL_NV_coverage_sample GL_EXT_occlusion_query_boolean GL_NV_occlusion_query_samples GL_NV_timer_query

I/DEBUG   (  142): debuggerd: 2014-04-12 12:36:46
I/DEBUG   (  142): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
I/DEBUG   (  142): Build fingerprint: 'htc/htc_europe/endeavoru:4.2.2/JDQ39/231174.2:user/release-keys'
I/DEBUG   (  142): Revision: '0'
I/DEBUG   (  142): pid: 4500, tid: 4533, name: UnityPreload  >>> com.Vali.Atomic <<<
I/DEBUG   (  142): debuggerd: checkTellHTCSettings
I/DEBUG   (  142): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 00000000
I/DEBUG   (  142):     r0 00000000  r1 00000000  r2 00005e40  r3 00000038
I/DEBUG   (  142):     r4 5ffe4c98  r5 00005e40  r6 00000038  r7 00000000
I/DEBUG   (  142):     r8 6064f1bc  r9 5ffe4c98  sl 00800101  fp 00005e40
I/DEBUG   (  142):     ip 00000000  sp 5ffe4c68  lr 5efb15ec  pc 5efb0808  cpsr 60000010
I/DEBUG   (  142):     d0  0000000000000000  d1  3f00000000000000
I/DEBUG   (  142):     d2  0000000000000000  d3  3f80000000000000
I/DEBUG   (  142):     d4  0000000000000000  d5  0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (  142):     d6  3f50239e00000000  d7  43284ccd434f0000
I/DEBUG   (  142):     d8  000000003f800000  d9  0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (  142):     d10 0000000000000000  d11 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (  142):     d12 0000000000000000  d13 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (  142):     d14 0000000000000000  d15 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (  142):     d16 3f8000003f800000  d17 3fafffffb67ea93f
I/DEBUG   (  142):     d18 3e826055b02bbc48  d19 bb2de24bbb5af90b
I/DEBUG   (  142):     d20 4000000000000000  d21 bd302b5727400000
I/DEBUG   (  142):     d22 be826055cc4fc2e6  d23 bf66c16c16bebd90
I/DEBUG   (  142):     d24 3fc555555555553c  d25 3ff6a09e60000000
I/DEBUG   (  142):     d26 3fd559354c7fec6b  d27 3fdb72733ea22406
I/DEBUG   (  142):     d28 3fe3363e908db2b5  d29 bfb5f61a00000000
I/DEBUG   (  142):     d30 4007504f00000000  d31 3fe2b80340000000
I/DEBUG   (  142):     scr 20000013
I/DEBUG   (  142):
I/DEBUG   (  142): backtrace:
I/DEBUG   (  142):     #00  pc 002c0808  /mnt/asec/com.Vali.Atomic-1/lib/libunity.so
I/DEBUG   (  142):     #01  pc 002c15e8  /mnt/asec/com.Vali.Atomic-1/lib/libunity.so
I/DEBUG   (  142):     #02  pc 002c6d60  /mnt/asec/com.Vali.Atomic-1/lib/libunity.so
I/DEBUG   (  142):     #03  pc 00299f04  /mnt/asec/com.Vali.Atomic-1/lib/libunity.so
I/DEBUG   (  142):     #04  pc 0028a10c  /mnt/asec/com.Vali.Atomic-1/lib/libunity.so
I/DEBUG   (  142):     #05  pc 0028a364  /mnt/asec/com.Vali.Atomic-1/lib/libunity.so
I/DEBUG   (  142):     #06  pc 002dab10  /mnt/asec/com.Vali.Atomic-1/lib/libunity.so
I/DEBUG   (  142):     #07  pc 0000e460  /system/lib/libc.so (__thread_entry+96)
I/DEBUG   (  142):     #08  pc 0000db28  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_create+196)
I/DEBUG   (  142):
I/DEBUG   (  142): stack:
I/DEBUG   (  142):          5ffe4c28  623b9b90
I/DEBUG   (  142):          5ffe4c2c  5edaaf98  /mnt/asec/com.Vali.Atomic-1/lib/libunity.so
I/DEBUG   (  142):          5ffe4c30  623b9b90
I/DEBUG   (  142):          5ffe4c34  5edab0a4  /mnt/asec/com.Vali.Atomic-1/lib/libunity.so
I/DEBUG   (  142):          5ffe4c38  623b9b90
I/DEBUG   (  142):          5ffe4c3c  5eee6d2c  /mnt/asec/com.Vali.Atomic-1/lib/libunity.so
I/DEBUG   (  142):          5ffe4c40  00000023
I/DEBUG   (  142):          5ffe4c44  00000001
I/DEBUG   (  142):          5ffe4c48  623b9b90
I/DEBUG   (  142):          5ffe4c4c  5eee6e28  /mnt/asec/com.Vali.Atomic-1/lib/libunity.so
I/DEBUG   (  142):          5ffe4c50  5f60fbe4  /mnt/asec/com.Vali.Atomic-1/lib/libunity.so
I/DEBUG   (  142):          5ffe4c54  00000042
I/DEBUG   (  142):          5ffe4c58  00002858
I/DEBUG   (  142):          5ffe4c5c  00000001
I/DEBUG   (  142):          5ffe4c60  df0027ad
I/DEBUG   (  142):          5ffe4c64  00000000
I/DEBUG   (  142):     #00  5ffe4c68  6064f170
I/DEBUG   (  142):          5ffe4c6c  606a202c
I/DEBUG   (  142):          5ffe4c70  623b9b90
I/DEBUG   (  142):          5ffe4c74  5efb15ec  /mnt/asec/com.Vali.Atomic-1/lib/libunity.so
I/DEBUG   (  142):     #01  5ffe4c78  605cd90c
I/DEBUG   (  142):          5ffe4c7c  605cd90c
I/DEBUG   (  142):          5ffe4c80  5ffe4cc8
I/DEBUG   (  142):          5ffe4c84  000000a2
I/DEBUG   (  142):          5ffe4c88  00000000
I/DEBUG   (  142):          5ffe4c8c  5ffe4c90
I/DEBUG   (  142):          5ffe4c90  00800101
I/DEBUG   (  142):          5ffe4c94  00000000
I/DEBUG   (  142):          5ffe4c98  5ffe4cc8
I/DEBUG   (  142):          5ffe4c9c  000000a2
I/DEBUG   (  142):          5ffe4ca0  00000000
I/DEBUG   (  142):          5ffe4ca4  00000000
I/DEBUG   (  142):          5ffe4ca8  ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (  142):          5ffe4cac  6004cdc0
I/DEBUG   (  142):          5ffe4cb0  605cd88c
I/DEBUG   (  142):          5ffe4cb4  00002858
I/DEBUG   (  142):          ........  ........
I/DEBUG   (  142):     #02  5ffe4d08  00000000
I/DEBUG   (  142):          5ffe4d0c  5ffe4d7c
I/DEBUG   (  142):          5ffe4d10  5ffe4d80
I/DEBUG   (  142):          5ffe4d14  6004cdd0
I/DEBUG   (  142):          5ffe4d18  605cdacc
I/DEBUG   (  142):          5ffe4d1c  605cd88c
I/DEBUG   (  142):          5ffe4d20  605cd800
I/DEBUG   (  142):          5ffe4d24  00000001
I/DEBUG   (  142):          5ffe4d28  605cd884
I/DEBUG   (  142):          5ffe4d2c  6004cdc8
I/DEBUG   (  142):          5ffe4d30  00000000
I/DEBUG   (  142):          5ffe4d34  5ffe4d7c
I/DEBUG   (  142):          5ffe4d38  5ffe4d80
I/DEBUG   (  142):          5ffe4d3c  6064f170
I/DEBUG   (  142):          5ffe4d40  0000029b
I/DEBUG   (  142):          5ffe4d44  5f829140
I/DEBUG   (  142):          ........  ........
I/DEBUG   (  142):
I/DEBUG   (  142): memory near r2:
I/DEBUG   (  142):     00005e20 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (  142):     00005e30 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (  142):     00005e40 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (  142):     00005e50 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (  142):     00005e60 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (  142):     00005e70 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (  142):     00005e80 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (  142):     00005e90 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (  142):     00005ea0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (  142):     00005eb0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (  142):     00005ec0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (  142):     00005ed0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (  142):     00005ee0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (  142):     00005ef0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (  142):     00005f00 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (  142):     00005f10 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (  142):
I/DEBUG   (  142): memory near r4:
I/DEBUG   (  142):     5ffe4c78 605cd90c 605cd90c 5ffe4cc8 000000a2
I/DEBUG   (  142):     5ffe4c88 00000000 5ffe4c90 00800101 00000000
I/DEBUG   (  142):     5ffe4c98 5ffe4cc8 000000a2 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (  142):     5ffe4ca8 ffffffff 6004cdc0 605cd88c 00002858
I/DEBUG   (  142):     5ffe4cb8 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (  142):     5ffe4cc8 00000000 00000000 60050490 4013f901
I/DEBUG   (  142):     5ffe4cd8 6270fb8c 6217c13c 5ffe4de4 0000008e
I/DEBUG   (  142):     5ffe4ce8 5ffe4de4 00002858 000000a0 6252576c
I/DEBUG   (  142):     5ffe4cf8 000000a2 5fffce2c 605cd924 5efb6d64
I/DEBUG   (  142):     5ffe4d08 00000000 5ffe4d7c 5ffe4d80 6004cdd0
I/DEBUG   (  142):     5ffe4d18 605cdacc 605cd88c 605cd800 00000001
I/DEBUG   (  142):     5ffe4d28 605cd884 6004cdc8 00000000 5ffe4d7c
I/DEBUG   (  142):     5ffe4d38 5ffe4d80 6064f170 0000029b 5f829140
I/DEBUG   (  142):     5ffe4d48 62525530 00000288 00000288 00000000
I/DEBUG   (  142):     5ffe4d58 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (  142):     5ffe4d68 00000000 00000000 00000010 5eda6288
I/DEBUG   (  142):
I/DEBUG   (  142): memory near r5:
I/DEBUG   (  142):     00005e20 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (  142):     00005e30 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (  142):     00005e40 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (  142):     00005e50 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (  142):     00005e60 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (  142):     00005e70 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (  142):     00005e80 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (  142):     00005e90 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (  142):     00005ea0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (  142):     00005eb0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (  142):     00005ec0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (  142):     00005ed0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (  142):     00005ee0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (  142):     00005ef0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (  142):     00005f00 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (  142):     00005f10 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (  142):
I/DEBUG   (  142): memory near r8:
I/DEBUG   (  142):     6064f19c 00000000 00000035 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (  142):     6064f1ac 00000019 00000000 00000400 00000000
I/DEBUG   (  142):     6064f1bc 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (  142):     6064f1cc 00000031 62524008 40179c90 0000000c
I/DEBUG   (  142):     6064f1dc 00000045 00000015 00000015 0000000c
I/DEBUG   (  142):     6064f1ec 00000009 00000000 00000018 000000b0
I/DEBUG   (  142):     6064f1fc 00000022 00000014 48000d0c 0488100e
I/DEBUG   (  142):     6064f20c 028c038b 0e44018e 0b0d4420 00000020
I/DEBUG   (  142):     6064f21c 000000d9 40179d38 40179d38 00000018
I/DEBUG   (  142):     6064f22c 00000062 0000003e 00000000 0000000c
I/DEBUG   (  142):     6064f23c 00000093 0000003c 0000003c ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (  142):     6064f24c 746e6d2f 6573612f 6f632f63 61562e6d
I/DEBUG   (  142):     6064f25c 412e696c 696d6f74 2f312d63 2e676b70
I/DEBUG   (  142):     6064f26c 2f6b7061 65737361 622f7374 442f6e69
I/DEBUG   (  142):     6064f27c 2f617461 6e69616d 61746144 00000070
I/DEBUG   (  142):     6064f28c 0000006a 00000053 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (  142):
I/DEBUG   (  142): memory near r9:
I/DEBUG   (  142):     5ffe4c78 605cd90c 605cd90c 5ffe4cc8 000000a2
I/DEBUG   (  142):     5ffe4c88 00000000 5ffe4c90 00800101 00000000
I/DEBUG   (  142):     5ffe4c98 5ffe4cc8 000000a2 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (  142):     5ffe4ca8 ffffffff 6004cdc0 605cd88c 00002858
I/DEBUG   (  142):     5ffe4cb8 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (  142):     5ffe4cc8 00000000 00000000 60050490 4013f901
I/DEBUG   (  142):     5ffe4cd8 6270fb8c 6217c13c 5ffe4de4 0000008e
I/DEBUG   (  142):     5ffe4ce8 5ffe4de4 00002858 000000a0 6252576c
I/DEBUG   (  142):     5ffe4cf8 000000a2 5fffce2c 605cd924 5efb6d64
I/DEBUG   (  142):     5ffe4d08 00000000 5ffe4d7c 5ffe4d80 6004cdd0
I/DEBUG   (  142):     5ffe4d18 605cdacc 605cd88c 605cd800 00000001
I/DEBUG   (  142):     5ffe4d28 605cd884 6004cdc8 00000000 5ffe4d7c
I/DEBUG   (  142):     5ffe4d38 5ffe4d80 6064f170 0000029b 5f829140
I/DEBUG   (  142):     5ffe4d48 62525530 00000288 00000288 00000000
I/DEBUG   (  142):     5ffe4d58 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (  142):     5ffe4d68 00000000 00000000 00000010 5eda6288
I/DEBUG   (  142):
I/DEBUG   (  142): memory near sl:
I/DEBUG   (  142):     008000e0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (  142):     008000f0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (  142):     00800100 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (  142):     00800110 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (  142):     00800120 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (  142):     00800130 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (  142):     00800140 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (  142):     00800150 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (  142):     00800160 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (  142):     00800170 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (  142):     00800180 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (  142):     00800190 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (  142):     008001a0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (  142):     008001b0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (  142):     008001c0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (  142):     008001d0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (  142):
I/DEBUG   (  142): memory near fp:
I/DEBUG   (  142):     00005e20 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (  142):     00005e30 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (  142):     00005e40 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (  142):     00005e50 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (  142):     00005e60 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (  142):     00005e70 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (  142):     00005e80 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (  142):     00005e90 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (  142):     00005ea0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (  142):     00005eb0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (  142):     00005ec0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (  142):     00005ed0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (  142):     00005ee0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (  142):     00005ef0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (  142):     00005f00 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (  142):     00005f10 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (  142):
I/DEBUG   (  142): memory near sp:
I/DEBUG   (  142):     5ffe4c48 623b9b90 5eee6e28 5f60fbe4 00000042
I/DEBUG   (  142):     5ffe4c58 00002858 00000001 df0027ad 00000000
I/DEBUG   (  142):     5ffe4c68 6064f170 606a202c 623b9b90 5efb15ec
I/DEBUG   (  142):     5ffe4c78 605cd90c 605cd90c 5ffe4cc8 000000a2
I/DEBUG   (  142):     5ffe4c88 00000000 5ffe4c90 00800101 00000000
I/DEBUG   (  142):     5ffe4c98 5ffe4cc8 000000a2 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (  142):     5ffe4ca8 ffffffff 6004cdc0 605cd88c 00002858
I/DEBUG   (  142):     5ffe4cb8 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (  142):     5ffe4cc8 00000000 00000000 60050490 4013f901
I/DEBUG   (  142):     5ffe4cd8 6270fb8c 6217c13c 5ffe4de4 0000008e
I/DEBUG   (  142):     5ffe4ce8 5ffe4de4 00002858 000000a0 6252576c
I/DEBUG   (  142):     5ffe4cf8 000000a2 5fffce2c 605cd924 5efb6d64
I/DEBUG   (  142):     5ffe4d08 00000000 5ffe4d7c 5ffe4d80 6004cdd0
I/DEBUG   (  142):     5ffe4d18 605cdacc 605cd88c 605cd800 00000001
I/DEBUG   (  142):     5ffe4d28 605cd884 6004cdc8 00000000 5ffe4d7c
I/DEBUG   (  142):     5ffe4d38 5ffe4d80 6064f170 0000029b 5f829140
I/DEBUG   (  142):
I/DEBUG   (  142): code around pc:
I/DEBUG   (  142):     5efb07e8 e8bd0010 eaffffc6 e92d4070 e1a04000
I/DEBUG   (  142):     5efb07f8 e1a06003 e1a00001 e584100c e1a05002
I/DEBUG   (  142):     5efb0808 e5913000 e0866005 e1a0e00f e593f014
I/DEBUG   (  142):     5efb0818 e1a01000 e5840014 e1a00005 ebf6ac01
I/DEBUG   (  142):     5efb0828 e584601c e5845018 e5840010 e1a00004
I/DEBUG   (  142):     5efb0838 ebffe9b2 e1a00004 e1a01005 e8bd4070
I/DEBUG   (  142):     5efb0848 eaffffaf e92d4070 e590c000 e5903004
I/DEBUG   (  142):     5efb0858 e1a04000 e5901010 e3a02000 e5905014
I/DEBUG   (  142):     5efb0868 e063300c e0253195 e1a01005 ebffff16
I/DEBUG   (  142):     5efb0878 e594300c e5941010 e1a00003 e5933000
I/DEBUG   (  142):     5efb0888 e1a0e00f e593f010 e3e03000 e1a00005
I/DEBUG   (  142):     5efb0898 e5843010 e8bd8070 e92d45f0 e24dd05c
I/DEBUG   (  142):     5efb08a8 e28d7010 e59f30ac e1a05001 e2876008
I/DEBUG   (  142):     5efb08b8 e3a04000 e1a08000 e08f3003 e1a00006
I/DEBUG   (  142):     5efb08c8 e1a0a002 e2833008 e58d1050 e58d304c
I/DEBUG   (  142):     5efb08d8 e58d4054 e58d4010 e58d4014 ebfff13e
I/DEBUG   (  142):
I/DEBUG   (  142): code around lr:
I/DEBUG   (  142):     5efb15cc e58da018 e1a00009 e58d701c e498104c
I/DEBUG   (  142):     5efb15dc e995000c e0822001 e5941048 ebfffc80
I/DEBUG   (  142):     5efb15ec e8980007 e28d3048 e8830007 e59d1014
I/DEBUG   (  142):     5efb15fc e5963000 e1a00006 e1a0e00f e593f040
I/DEBUG   (  142):     5efb160c e1a00009 ebfffc8d e59dc010 e5958008
I/DEBUG   (  142):     5efb161c e08bc00c e06ca000 e15a0008 0a000018
I/DEBUG   (  142):     5efb162c e1d501f0 e3500072 0a000019 ebf7ec08
I/DEBUG   (  142):     5efb163c e59f113c e1a0300a e08f1001 e5902000
I/DEBUG   (  142):     5efb164c e28d0058 e58d8000 eb00769a e59f2124
I/DEBUG   (  142):     5efb165c e1a01007 e59d0058 e3003495 e08f2002
I/DEBUG   (  142):     5efb166c e3a0c001 e58d7004 e58d7008 e58dc000
I/DEBUG   (  142):     5efb167c eb007edb e59d0058 e28d1064 e240000c
I/DEBUG   (  142):     5efb168c eb1861f7 e59d3098 e3a02000 e5c32000
I/DEBUG   (  142):     5efb169c eaffffba e59f10e0 e28d5054 e1a0200a
I/DEBUG   (  142):     5efb16ac e1a03008 e1a00005 e08f1001 eb007681
I/DEBUG   (  142):     5efb16bc e59f20c8 e59d0054 e1a01007 e3003491
I/ActivityManager(  515): Recipient 4500
I/ActivityManager(  515): Process com.Vali.Atomic (pid 4500) has died.
W/ActivityManager(  515): Force removing ActivityRecord{430bab48 u0 com.Vali.Atomic/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerNativeActivity}: app died, no saved
state
W/ActivityManager(  515): handleTopAppChanged(): The previous AP is died unexpectedly.
W/dalvikvm(  515): [GC Control] disableGcForExternalAlloc: true
W/dalvikvm(  515): [GC Control] disableGcForExternalAlloc: false
W/dalvikvm(  515): [GC Control] disableGcForExternalAlloc: true
W/dalvikvm(  515): [GC Control] disableGcForExternalAlloc: false
```

Is it some memory allocation problem, a Unity bug or I did something wrong? Thank you for your time.

[Edited] It freaking works if build in development mode! Any reason for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I faced a similar problem with my Unity application, except development mode continued to crash.

In my code I had declared class member AudioClips and initialized them as they were declared. I read somewhere that this should not be done in Unity, so I moved them to where I needed them and it fixed the issue.

This seems a little counter-intuitive as I'm used to the idea of preloading as much as possible for optimization purposes.